# Passing an entire array from one method to another

Tags: c#

how do i pass an array from one method to another?
Also in the main method, shuffled some array receive an error saying that it takes zero arguments, but what argument am i suppose to put in there?
Some sample code is greatly appreciated

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       ShuffledSomeArray();
        DoSomethingWithArray();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
     static string[] ShuffledSomeArray(string [] array)
    {
        array = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 4; i>=0; i--)
        {
            int shuffle = rnd.Next(0, i);
           string rndpick = array[shuffle];
           array[shuffle] = array[i];
                array[i] = rndpick;
            Console.Write(array[i]);
        }

    }
    static void DoSomethingWithArray()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you pass any other parameter.

Comment: Although I think that google should have been your first choice for such a question: Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyfeyz71.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] arr = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        string[] result = ShuffledSomeArray(arr);
        DoSomethingWithArray(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
     static string[] ShuffledSomeArray(string [] array)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 4; i>=0; i--)
        {
            int shuffle = rnd.Next(0, i);
           string rndpick = array[shuffle];
           array[shuffle] = array[i];
                array[i] = rndpick;
            Console.Write(array[i]);
        }

    }
    static void DoSomethingWithArray(string[] array)
    {

    }
}
```